# How to display images using vaadin ClassResource class and Tomcat as web server?

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin

I have created a Vaadin application that tries to use the ClassResource vaadin class to load some icons along with some vaadin components but I cannot see the icons in the final application.
In icons place I see a blue question mark.
The application is deployed on tomcat (latest version).
Here is part of the code.

IconsUI.java :

```
tf.setIcon(new ClassResource("email.png"));
cb.setIcon(new ClassResource("note.png"));
ta.setIcon(new ClassResource("document.png"));
bt.setIcon(new ClassResource("ok.png"));
```

These image files are located in the same package as the IconsUI.java class.

My web.xml is the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
           version="3.0">

    <display-name>icons</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>
            Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Icons Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>
                Vaadin UI class to use</description>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>MavenVaadinIcons.IconsUI</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Icons Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: where are your icons placed?

Comment: They are meant to beautify the components but the problem is that they are not get loaded by tomcat.

Comment: where have you placed them in your project (path)?

Comment: In the same package with the java class that is trying to use them(IconsUI.java)

Comment: Do you use Maven? If so then the icons must be placed into the src/main/resources/ folder.

Comment: Yes I am using Maven, but I have no resources folder.Only main/java and main/webapp.

Answer (score 4):

To load an image using `ClassResource`, your images should be available in the classpath of your final web application. You can add your images to classpath by placing the images in `src/main/resources` folder of your maven source.

Also, you need to add a leading `/` character to image file names. The `ClassResource` constructor you used doesn't have a `Class` argument, so it uses the current UI class as the class. The resource you specified is looked up in the same package as the UI class. By adding a leading `/` character, the file will be looked up in the classpath root.

```
tf.setIcon(new ClassResource("/email.png"));
cb.setIcon(new ClassResource("/note.png"));
ta.setIcon(new ClassResource("/document.png"));
bt.setIcon(new ClassResource("/ok.png"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you use Maven, you must place resource files into the `src/main/resources` folder. If you don't have that folder, you can create it.

If your image's path is for example `src/main/java/com/example/email.png` put it into a corresponding package in resources: `src/main/resources/com/example/email.png`.

Comment: I've already tried to put them in the main/resources folder that I created manually but I still cannot see them loading.

Comment: Do you believe that I should change the ClassResource class argument?

Comment: Did you put those into the correct package in resources folder? However, I would consider to place the images into theme and use ThemeResource.

Comment: I have already seen the theme solution, but why can't I use ClassResource class as the author of the book I read does?(Vaadin 7 UI Design By Example).Basically I have not been able to access any files at all in other projects of this book too. Does tomcat is so problematic when it comes to vaadin projects?

Comment: ClassResources work when you have images in correct place in class path.

Comment: I agree, but how can I find the class path?

Comment: When I deploy the application, I go to view page source and the image src is the following : http://localhost:8080/APP/connector/0/4/icon/note.png

Comment: The use of ThemeResource worked, but you must change your answer since I cannot accept a comment as an answer!